# Comparing three tsv files to check for similar items and updating the differences in the original file

Tags: python, csv

So I have three `.tsv` files, namely `file1.tsv`, `file2.tsv` and `file3.tsv`, and they are as follows:

file1.tsv =

```
ID       Name
1        Abby
2        Lisa
3        
4        John
5              
6        Kevin
7        Joe
8        Sasha
9        Stuart
10       Amy
```

file2.tsv =

```
ID       Name
8        Sasha
3        Iris
9        Stuart
```

file3.tsv =

```
ID       Name
10       Amy
5        Kelly
6        Kevin
7        Joe
```

I need to parse the first file into ID and Names and check for the rows where the entry IDs have empty names. Then I have to check for those specific IDs in `file2.tsv`, if there is a matching name for that ID, I have to update `file1.tsv` with it. In case I don't find matches for all the empty IDs in `file2.tsv`, I will have to check for them in `file3.tsv`, which will result in all the appropriate matching of IDs and names, which again needs to be updated in `file1.tsv`.

The `output.tsv` file should have all the IDs showing their corresponding names, as follows:

```
ID       Name
1        Abby
2        Lisa
3        Iris
4        John
5        Kelly      
6        Kevin
7        Joe
8        Sasha
9        Stuart
10       Amy
```

Now, here is what I tried:

```
import csv
import sys

f1 = open("file1.tsv")
read_tsv = csv.reader(f1, delimiter="\t", quotechar='"')

with open('new.tsv', 'w', newline='') as g_output: #to save the empty entry IDs in a separate file
  tsv_new = csv.writer(g_output, delimiter='\t')
  for row in read_tsv:
    if row[1] == '':            
      print(row)
      tsv_new.writerow(row)

g_output.close()
f1.close()

entry_ID = input('Enter ID number to find:\n')
f2 = csv.reader(open('file2.tsv'), delimiter="\t")

with open('output.tsv', 'a', newline='') as f_output: #to append the output to this new file
  tsv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')
  for row in f2:
    if entry_ID == row[0]:
      print(row)
      tsv_output.writerow(row)
f_output.close()
f2.close()
```

Similarly, check in `file3.tsv`. However, it doesn't seem to work, and I don't want to manually look for entry IDs, but want to automate the process by manipulation of file handling and using loops. I am new to Python and this seems tricky

This here is an example because my original three `.tsv` files are huge, and manual update of IDs will not be feasible.

Comment: Read each file directly into a PANDAS data frame.  Remove empty entries and merge.  Write to CSV again.  Since you have no conflicts among files, that should handle your problem in less than 5 lines of code.

Comment: @Prune thank you for that, but I am looking to deal with this preferentially without any fancy modules but built-in functionalities. The basic approach, really.

Comment: In that case, do the same with your dicts.  remove empty entries and simply merge (update) the three dicts.

Comment: Since you already imported the `csv` package, creating a reader and a writer, I don't see how a data frame crosses the line into your judgment of "fancy modules".

Comment: Thank you so much @Prune, this helped me. And I understand that it is kind of dumb not to use PANDAS here, but I thought better than to argue with my boss. Plus, this will help me learn better I hope.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is your best bet, as the keys are unique you can just read each row in and assign the key as the `ID`. Obviously files read in later will overwrite any existing identical keys. Secondly you can skip any empty rows or rows containing no name:

```
import csv

data = {}

for filename in ['file1.tsv', 'file2.tsv', 'file3.tsv']:
    with open(filename, newline='') as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t')
        header = next(csv_input)
        
        for row in csv_input:
            if len(row) == 2 and row[1]:
                data[int(row[0])] = row[1]      # convert the ID to an int to ensure it is numerically sorted
            
with open('output.tsv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')
    csv_output.writerow(header)
    csv_output.writerows(sorted(data.items()))
```

This would give you an output file containing:

```
ID  Name
1   Abby
2   Lisa
4   John
5   Kelly
6   Kevin
7   Joe
8   Sasha
9   Stuart
10  Amy
```

`data` could also then be used to look up an `ID`:

```
>> print(data[9])
>> Stuart
```